# How often refer a list of symbols

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I know how to make a list of symbols with the help of glossaries, but I am facing a style problem that I'd like the community help me solve.

I writing my thesis in mathematics, so I have many symbols, most of which are "new" and go throughout all the work. I am wondering how often should I use a symbol as to be referred in glossary?

In practice, should I refer only the first appearance in a page? That looks too much to me. What about once a section? Maybe too less...

So, since in this case LaTeX doesn't seem to have a standard to refer to (or at least that I can find), what are the rules that I should follow?

Comment: I don't think this is LaTeX question at all -- it's more about typography and style in general

Comment: Shouldn't you reference it's definition ?

Comment: Do you mean the number of times a symbol is indexed (each number added to the location list)?  I think the general rule is to index important instances of the symbol (for example, when introducing it in the main text or providing some information about it) and omit indexing it when only using the symbol in passing.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer my only knowledge about typography is that I let LaTeX do all the dirty work and I try to avoid as much as possible touching anything, when not strictly needed. Since this is a community of LaTeX lovers and experts, some of us might have knowledge of typography and such, especially because this is not a standard that LaTeX takes care of, so that's why I wrote here. If you know somewhere else where I should ask, that would be great to know (maybe another SE site?) :)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot yes, that was my thought, but let say that I prove a lot of important things about this symbol in 3-4 consequent pages. Should I refer all of them? Or just the first? Or maybe the first and then with a command - that I do not know yet about - say something like "20ff."?

Comment: @dadexix86: Well, I don't know a 'site' about this really -- all I wanted to say is that there is no clear style, in my point of view and it's rather a personal issue.

Comment: this is really a mathematics question.  the tradition in mathematics is that an author will define (perhaps in the introduction, perhaps just before a symbol is used) any unusual or special notation.  there may be a glossary or list of symbols, but not necessarily; for a book or dissertation, it's probably a good idea, but not every use of a symbol or special notation needs to be indexed from it, only the place where each is defined, or especially important uses.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments :) In the end, I think I'll refer to it, if needed, no more than once per subsection.